# Boost Log severity levels versus syslog severity levels

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm trying to modify my application to use the Boost Log library instead of logging into `syslog`. Boost Log severity levels are defined in `boost/log/trivial.hpp`, where the most serious level has **maximal** numeric number (5):

```
enum severity_level
{
    trace,
    debug,
    info,
    warning,
    error,
    fatal
};
```

However, the [`syslog`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) defines more severity levels, which are actually standardized by the [RFC5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5424) - and most serious level has **minimal** numeric number (0).

Is it any way to define my own `MySeverityLevels` enumeration type (probably close to the RFC5424) and use various Boost Log loggers (`severity_logger`, for instance) with this new type, including the filtering by severity level?

Comment: not really clear what is the problem. Can you invent a mapping from boost severity levels to syslog severity levels? Yes, why not?

Comment: @user463035818 - yes, I can - but it wouldn't be an answer for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. The code below implements what I wanted:

```
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

enum class MySeverityLevel
{
  panic,
  alert,
  critical,
  error,
  warning,
  notice,
  info,
  debug
};

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(Severity, "Severity", MySeverityLevel)

int main()
{
  // ------ define sink
  logging::add_file_log
  (
    keywords::file_name = "test.log",
    keywords::filter = (Severity <= MySeverityLevel::error)
  );
  // ------ define logger
  src::severity_logger<MySeverityLevel> lg;
  // ------ output logging messages
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, MySeverityLevel::panic) << "This is panic";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, MySeverityLevel::debug) << "This is debug";
}
```

It was no need to use any mappings.

Answer (score 1):

`<boost_root>/libs/log/example/native_syslog` contains example of custom log levels, i.e. create an enumeration for your severity levels:

```
//! Define application-specific severity levels
enum severity_levels
{
    /* your own level */
    normal = 2,
    warning = 1,
    error = 0
};
```

and register it in your sink

```
    // Create a syslog sink
    shared_ptr< sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::syslog_backend > > sink(
        new sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::syslog_backend >(
            keywords::use_impl = sinks::syslog::native,
            keywords::facility = sinks::syslog::local7));
     ........................
    // We'll have to map our custom levels to the syslog levels
    sinks::syslog::custom_severity_mapping< severity_levels > mapping("Severity");
    mapping[normal] = sinks::syslog::info;
    mapping[warning] = sinks::syslog::warning;
    mapping[error] = sinks::syslog::critical;

    sink->locked_backend()->set_severity_mapper(mapping);

    // Add the sink to the core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
```